# What is the meaning of top level and low level PHP scripts?

Tags: php, oop, terminology

In many PHP, PHP MVC, and PHP object oriented books, they refer to various scripts as either top level or low level.  What does it mean if a PHP script is a top level or low level PHP script?

> In formal MCV structures, you would use objects as Controllers. Here, individual PHP scripts will act as the Controllers. However, just as in formal MVC, the Controllers will not contain or generate any HTML, pushing that onto the views, which are individual HTML files. As you'll see, the View files are primarily HTML, with very little logic, which is to say only the bare minimum of PHP code. The Models will always be classes. The Controllers are represented by top-level PHP scripts.

Comment: You mean Top level domain? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pavlovich the book is referring to top-level PHP scripts.  The top-level domains wiki was a good read though and I appreciate it.

Comment: @LaurenceWingo You should update the question instead of adding explanations in comment. Piece of code could help too ;-)

Comment: @LucM I don't see how any piece of code is concerned here :p

Comment: @LucM thanks for your insight as this process is very very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by "top level" in this instance they are simply referring to the idea that the script which hold the controller is at the top of the chain in your application stack, its the entry point of the application, first place which gets hit in your code base when you access any url.

Historically php applications used to be written in a way that the files which contained html was "top level" with some php embedded in them.

Now popular php frameworks use MVC style architecture where entry point to the application is the php only controller and files holding html are included only later in the call stack.

Comment: Thanks @skyjur that really made sense!